# How to calculate RAM memory needed for training?

Tags: machine-learning, memory, keras

How can I calculate RAM memory needed for training a keras model? I want to calculate this because I sometimes encounter the exceeds system memory error when training models. Here is my model, for example:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 30, 30, 32)        320
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 32)        9248
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 14, 14, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 64)        18496
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 64)        36928
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 5, 64)          0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1600)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               204928
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290
=================================================================
Total params: 271,210
Trainable params: 271,210
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: This answer to a related question will be helpful for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54308456/2641587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each parameter is a 32-bit datatype (single-precision floating point, 4 bytes). Your memory usage should be somewhere around: (# of params) * 4B

In this case: 271,210 * 4B = 1084840B =~ 1MB

However, there is an important consideration to keep in mind. This is assuming a batch size of 1, i.e. you're loading in 1 input at a time. If you are using minibatch (typical batch size of 32 or 64) then you'll have to multiply that memory calculation by the size of the batch. If you are using *batch gradient descent*, then you may be using your entire dataset on each batch. In this case, your memory requirements could be enormous.

This analysis inspired by: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/cnn-memory-consumption